# ASP.NET WebAPI Custom route not getting hit, returning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have setup this custom route for a method in a controller:

```
[HttpPost, Route("imagconv/{format1}/to/{format2}")]
public HttpResponseMessage imagconv( [FromUri] string format1, [FromUri] string format2)
```

The route on the controller is:

```
[RoutePrefix("convert")]
public class DocumentConvertController : ApiController
```

And I am trying to call it in Postman with this example:

```
http:// ...server... /convert/imageconv/psd/to/png
```

And instead of getting the result, I am getting a 404 error.

Here is what is in my RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?  This seems straightforward.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in the route definition, it was missing an "e".